# Show the photo after the hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/G4eFT/1/

I want that when the mouse hovers the first image, it would also expose hidden photos with class `other` to the right.

But I am doing something wrong.

Could you give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Please paste your code here, not on some other website. StackOverflow is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers; what happens when jsfiddle shuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your fiddle that does what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/G4eFT/14/

The idea is that the "other" images go into a "hider" div that has an absolute position relative to the div containing the text you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Now, its working for showing only first image with class 'other'. Do you want to show all images with this class? Then remove "position:absolute;" from your css, so it would be:

```
.other
{
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, show the hidden images side by side?

Remove the positions from the classes first and other. And remove the float:left from the div text, so it can appear below the images.